# check if cursor returns anything

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can you in a procedure function in mysql check if the cursor returns anything?

Is it possible to avoid doing the `IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stock ...` and instead check up on the `_cur` variable somehow?

## procedure function

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `stock_first_available_id` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`dynaccount`@`localhost` FUNCTION `stock_first_available_id`(_running_total_limit INT, _product_id INT, _group_id INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE _running_count INT default 0;
    DECLARE _id INT;
    DECLARE _current_id INT;
    DECLARE _sum_count INT;
    DECLARE _cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id, count FROM stock WHERE group_id=_group_id && type=2 && product_id=_product_id ORDER BY time DESC, id DESC;
    
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stock WHERE group_id=_group_id && type=2 && product_id=_product_id) = 0 THEN
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
    
    OPEN _cur;
    
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH _cur INTO _id, _sum_count;
        
        SET _running_count = _running_count + _sum_count;
        SET _current_id = _id;
        
        IF _running_count > _running_total_limit THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP read_loop;
    
    CLOSE _cur;
    
    RETURN _current_id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I don't understand. Cursors don't "return" anything. Perhaps you can expand upon what your procedure is trying to do.

Comment: @clarkk I noticed I'd left this out of my cursor about 20 minutes ago :-) Glad to see you raised this as a new question - it's always good to raise a new topic.

Comment: @dash, and thanks for the help.. you just introduced my to a new powerful tool :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a continue handler to your cursor. See exanples from MySQL documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html